# mongo queryPlanner using correct index even though query field order doesn't match index fields order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In mongo's docu it says that order fields is important for index:

> The order of the fields listed in a compound index is important. The index will contain references to documents sorted first by the values of the item field and, within each value of the item field, sorted by values of the stock field. See Sort Order for more information.

[source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#:%7E:text=The%20order%20of%20the%20fields,Sort%20Order%20for%20more%20information.)

When I try this query:

```
db.getCollection('foobar').find({       
'target.propertyId': {
    $in: [
        ObjectId('01'), ///...
    ]
},
// NOTICE ownerId at end of query but queryPlanner still know which index to hit the one with ownerId at first
ownerId: ObjectId('02')} 
)
.explain('executionStats')
```

If I check queryPlanner I see it automatically selects the correct index I want it to select: the one that has `ownerId` at beginning. So does this means field order is not 100% needed to match an index?

Comment: The ordering of the fields in the index _matters_, and the ordering of fields in a query filter _do not matter_.